# htaccess ssl redirect on multidomain Website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have a TYPO3 Setup with several Domains and Subdomains.

domain1.com works well on https, domain1.com/stuff redirects to https://domain1.com/stuff.

Someone already wrote this into the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

domain2.com was not set up for https until now. It is now and I've got that weired behaviour: domain2.com redirects to https://domain2.com. But once I go further down, it wont (domain2.com/stuff wont redirect).

Could someone point out whats wrong with that htaccess code? If that one is correct, I have du dig further down - that htaccess is a clusterfuck.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this question: My solution was to use this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
```

instead of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

For some reason, the secon one didn't work on the other domains. If someone has an explaination for this, that would be great!